# Python Reddit API converting gifv to readable mp4

Tags: python, gif, mp4, imgur, praw

I am completely stuck as when dabbling in Reddit's API aka Praw I wanted to learn to save the number 1 hottest post as an mp4 however Reddit saves all of their gifs on Imgur which convert all gifs to gifv, how would I go around converting the gifv to mp4 so I can read them? Btw simply renaming it seems to lead to corruption.
This is my code so far: (details have been xxxx'd for confidentiality)

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id ="xxxx" , client_secret ="xxxx", username = "xxxx", password ="xxxx", user_agent="xxxx")

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("dankmemes")

hot_dm = subreddit.hot(limit=1);

for sub in hot_dm:
    print(sub)
    url = sub.url     
    print(url)
    print(sub.permalink)
    meme = requests.get(url)
    newF = open("{}.mp4".format(sub), "wb") #here the file is created but when played is corrupted
    newF.write(meme.content)
    newF.close()
```

Comment: It seems easier to just avoid gifv as a whole since it is only a format created by Imgur with not much detail on it or conversion protocols, which may mean this could be unanswerable for a long time haha

Answer (score 0):

Some posts already have an mp4 conversion inside the preview > variants portion of the json response.

Therefore to download only those posts that have a gif and therefore have an mp4 version you could do something like this:

```
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("dankmemes")

hot_dm = subreddit.hot(limit=10)

for sub in hot_dm:
    if sub.selftext == "": # check that the post is a link to some content (image/video/link)
        continue

    try: # try to access variants and catch the exception thrown
        has_variants = sub.preview['images'][0]['variants'] # variants contain both gif and mp4 versions (if available)
    except AttributeError: 
        continue # no conversion available as variants doesn't exist

    if 'mp4' not in has_variants: # check that there is an mp4 conversion available
        continue

    mp4_video = has_variants['mp4']['source']['url']
    
    print(sub, sub.url, sub.permalink)
    meme = requests.get(mp4_video)
    with open(f"{sub}.mp4", "wb") as newF:
        newF.write(meme.content)
```

Though you are most likely going to want to increase the limit of posts that you look through when searching through hot as the first post may be a pinned post (usually some rules about the subreddit), this is why I initially checked the selftext. In addition, there may be other posts that are only images, therefore with a small limit you might not return any posts that could be converted to mp4s.